# How can I directly obtain the item from this list comprehension?

Tags: python, list

Here's part of the code I'm working on in Python:

```
def ee(mid_circ = False):
    initial_layout = [[1,0] if mid_circ == True else [1,2,3,0]]
    return initial_layout
```

However, the output is either `[[1,0]]` or `[[1,2,3,0]]`. Is there a way I can directly obtain `[1,0]` or `[1,2,3,0]` from the code?

Comment: `return initial_layout[0]`

Comment: @Abdul Niyas P M Thanks, but is there a way I can modify the list comprehension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). You are simply constructing a list consisting of a single item (which also happens to be a list).

You should simply remove the outer brackets, i.e.

```
initial_layout = [1,0] if mid_circ else [1,2,3,0]
```

Note that I've also dropped the redundant `== True` check.

Answer (score 0):

@selcuk is correct, that's not a list comprehension.

Lists in lists are hard to follow.
local variables are cheap and fast. Use them.

```
def ee(mid_circ=False):

    mc = [1,0]
    non_mc = [1,2,3,0]

    return (non_mc,mc)[mid_circ]
```